# Change CSS of another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I have 2 Views. I want to change Style of the 2nd Element when the first element is active **WITHOUT** Modifying the First Element

```
#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}   
#content{
  padding-right:100px;
}
```

These are the 2 elements. When the SideBar is active, i want the Content of the page to get a padding of 100px on the right without changing anything from the sidebar

I know what i could do this

```
#sidebar.active , ##content {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right:100px;
}
```

But this would give the Sidebar also a padding of 100px which i dont want. I want to affect the CONTENT ONLY when the SideBar is Active. Any help is appreciated

Comment: To do this in pure css, your two elements have to be related in the DOM.  Are they?  And if so, how?  Can you show us an example of their markup?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could achive this with pure CSS, depending on your HTML markup.

**Solution 1 (IF #content is right "next" to #sidebar in your HTML):**

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
  /* for demonstration */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  
  margin-left: 0;
}

#content {
  /* for demonstration */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sidebar.active + #content {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    INACTIVE sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar" class="active">
    ACTIVE sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2 (IF #content is a child of #sidebar in your HTML):**

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

#sidebar {
  /* for demonstration */
  width: ;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;

  margin-left: 0;
}

#content {
  /* for demonstration */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#sidebar.active #content {
  padding-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    INACTIVE sidebar

    <div id="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar" class="active">
    ACTIVE sidebar
    <div id="content">
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```